# KeyNotFoundException: SQLCE Database Exception

Tags: c#, compact-framework, sql-server-ce

I am using a dataSet in C#. I have done a direct count for the number of items in
the SQL CE database, so I know how many items that I have in the database. There are no deletions in the the database.

I get the following unexplained exception(s) :

**A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException' occurred in System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll**

**A first chance exception of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll KeyNotFoundException**

This manifests where the communication locks with the SQL CE database.

Does anyone know what causes this and how this can be fixed?

I have searched online and am having no luck to any solutions for this :-(

```
        // List to be created
        List<TableDat> result = null;
        lock (_sqlcn)
        {
            // Assumes that connection is a valid SqlConnection object.
            SqlCeDataAdapter adapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter(orderSQL, _sqlcn);
            try
            {
                // DataSet that will be returned.
                System.Data.DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
                int count = adapter.Fill(ds, currentIndex, PageSize, "Logs");


                //Iterate through the table and in the List 
                foreach (System.Data.DataRow myDataRow in ds.Tables["Logs"].Rows)
                {
                    if (result == null)
                    {
                        result = new List<TableDat>();
                    }
                    result.Add(
                              new TableDat(
                                  (int)myDataRow[Resources.ID],
                                  (DateTime)myDataRow[Resources.TimeStamp],
                                  (int)myDataRow[Resources.EVENTLOG_SID],
                                  (int)myDataRow[Resources.EVENTLOG_EID])
                              );

                }
                // Set the dataSet object to NULL : No longer needed as the list 
                // has  been populated
                ds = null;
            }
```

The biggest problem I see is that this stops the SQL CE database working. Soz, I cannot make out what I should do in the exception handling here as I get nothing in my list which means that the caller has no details for the list??

This just manifests itself. I am looking for a solution which can handle the exception and also to know why my database is behaving as such :-(

Stack Trace looks like:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException' occurred in System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException' occurred in System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
KeyNotFoundException
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

Comment: I would also include the full stack trace of both exceptions

Comment: an aside - the assignment of ds to null is not needed (and can actually cause degraded performance)

Comment: DataSet also implements IDisposable so you should put it into a using block

Comment: locking on objects not of your control is also a bad practice. You have no idea whether other people are using the same object for locking (though this too is bad practice) and can cause deadlocks

Comment: A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException' occurred in System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException' occurred in System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
KeyNotFoundException

Comment: When I attempt to use 
                    // DataSet that will be returned.
                    using(DataSet ds = new DataSet())
This gives me an error saying that dataSet must be implicitly convertible to IDisposable? Any ideas

Comment: System.Data.DataSet extends MarshalByValueComponent which is IDisposable. Not sure why you'd get that error: `   using(System.Data.DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet()) {}` compiles just fine for me. Are you using a different DataSet from somewhere?
Whilst it's dispose currently does nothing you should not rely on that and dispose of everything implementing disposable in a timely, safe fashion.

Comment: Also that is not the full stack trace. that would be sufficiently big as to merit inclusion in the question (someone who knows can always edit it to be smaller)

Comment: I know that there is a partial implementation in a class which won't allow me to use the full one so I have had to use the complete assembly path. I agree with the using and added this. This doe snot resolve what I see as the exception happens and there is nothing apart from what I provided in the stack trace. I am using it as part of a web access and that stops when the key not found exception is raised.

Comment: I am realy confused and am finding it hard to follow on what I can do to stop the exception occurring and to make the code more robust :-(

Comment: The value for the currentIndex is passed by the calling function, which has used a count(*) to determine the number of items in the database. Because I cannot cache the massive database I need to get chunks of data and populate each of the row data into a list. This is then used to draw up a table in a web page. I pass down the current index as a minus from the previous index value. It always starts from zero then goes up incremently. I am new in understanding how I can resolve this exception. Please help :-)

Comment: Soz! What do you mean by this? Please can you provide an example. Is there somethng I am doing incorrect when using the dataSet object. The database I am accessing information from can potentially be very big in which I need to chunk the accesses. If I use a execute/read I need to iterate through. This is costly and time consuming :-( Any ideas???

Answer (score 2):

Usually you don't really need to worry about first chance exceptions. They are usually anticipated and handled by the lower level code inside the dll.

There's a decent write-up on first chance exceptions [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/105675).

You can also [disable these messages](http://www.helixoft.com/blog/archives/24) in Visual Studio. (For VS 2005... not sure on 2008).

Comment: No changes as I have already unset the Redirect all Output Window text to the Immediate Window. Once I get the exception it stops the database access.

Comment: Please can you explain this further?? What can cause these?? How can I get rid of them??